# LayoutParams not working

Tags: java, android, layoutparams

I am programming an app which generates all of its layout programmatically. I am looking to place an array of `ImageView[]` depending on their index. But it looks like the `LayoutParams` doesn't do anything since all the `ImageView`s are being superposed. Here is the code I am using:

```
for (int i=0; i<tiles; i++){
        Log.i("Setting up tile", "#" + i);
        tileParams.removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
        tileParams.removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START);
        tileParams.removeRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW);
        tileParams.removeRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF);
        if (((double)i/columns) == Math.round(i/columns)){
            if (i == 0){
                tileParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
                tileParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START);
            } else {
                tileParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, tileView[i-columns].getId());
                tileParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START);
            }
        } else {
            tileParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, tileView[i-1].getId());
        }
        tileView[i].setLayoutParams(tileParams);
        grid.addView(tileView[i]);
}
```

Here, "grid" is a `RelativeLayout` and "tileParams" is a `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`.

PS: I know that the `if`
 methods are used correctly at the required time, and the `ImageView`s have their ids set using `iv.setId(View.generateViewId())`.

Comment: what is the reason of doing this that way? i mean by calling `addRule` / `removeRule` from your java code? how do you want to layout your views?

Comment: I call `removeRule` because the `LayoutPrams` is initialized outside the `if` method

Comment: You should probably create a new LayoutParams every iteration. Currently all views share the same object so they all get the same rules, that of the last tile.

Comment: That's why I removeRules

Comment: but `setLayoutParams` does not deep copy the input parameter, so on every iteration the same layout param is used

Comment: I just tried to make 3 different `layoutParams` as you suggested, but the `ImageView`s are still superposed.

Comment: how do you want to layout your views? cannot you use other existing layouts?

Comment: @pskink There are two parameters passed with an Intent: int rows   and int columns.  Then `ImageView[rows*columns]` is initialized and the images are displayed in a table-like layout. I already tried to use a `TableLayout` but same thing happens. And this if method just works fine to indentify where images should be placed.

Comment: so if this is so simple grid then make a custom `ViewGroup` class and override `onLayout` (and maybe `onMeasure`) method - inside `onLayout` iterate over each child view and call `layout` method

Comment: Doesn't `onLayout` work the same way as `LayoutParams`?

Comment: if you dont want a custom `ViewGroup` then use something like [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/D7fVMukh)